# clang, gcc, and ignored qualifiers: who is right?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, qualifiers, boringssl

I found a difference in behavior between gcc and clang when compiling BoringSSL, and was able to whittle it down to the following test case to illustrate:

```cpp
typedef char *OPENSSL_STRING;
#if USE_TYPEDEF
#define constptr const OPENSSL_STRING
#else
#define constptr const char *
#endif

int
foo (const void **ap)
{
    constptr a = (constptr) *ap;
    return a != 0;
}
```

I tested four scenarios as follows:

```sh
sh$ g++ -c t2.cc -Wignored-qualifiers -DUSE_TYPEDEF
t2.cc: In function ‘int foo(const void**)’:
t2.cc:11:30: warning: type qualifiers ignored on cast result type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
   11 |     constptr a = (constptr) *ap;
      |                              ^~
sh$ g++ -c t2.cc -Wignored-qualifiers 
sh$ clang++ -c t2.cc -Wignored-qualifiers -DUSE_TYPEDEF
sh$ clang++ -c t2.cc -Wignored-qualifiers 
sh$
```

Is this a bug in gcc -- or is there something more going on that I don't understand?

---

For reference: the warning is [in BoringSSL's stack.h](https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl/+/565226278d6b863672bb5c3f24197d8bb6e58b50/include/openssl/stack.h#296)

Comment: You're missing `main()` in your testcase.

Comment: The existence of this macro is utterly baffling. Both branches are identical.

Comment: Warnings are just warnings.... See C++ standard like [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) and write your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to produce more warnings

Comment: Is that macro from, or totally representative of, BoringSSL? It seems broken _and_ pointless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given `const OPENSSL_STRING`, `const` is qualified on the typedef `OPENSSL_STRING` itself, so the type would be `char * const`, i.e. `const` pointer to non-const `char` (note that it's not `const char *`). Gcc is just trying to tell you that as the cast result the `const` part is ignored. i.e. `(char * const) *ap;` has the same effect as `(char *) *ap;`.

Changing the type to `int` might be clearer.

```
const int i = (int) 0;       // a weird conversion
const int i = (const int) 0; // same effect as above
```

Comment: So the macro seems broken, right? Or at least, it doesn't do what e.g. tadman in the comments intuitively thought/expected it to do, and there's no apparent reason for it to exist either way.

Comment: Oh, I see! So it's clang that should complain about it, but does not.

Comment: @underscore_d I'm not sure about OP's intent, using the macro or using `const OPENSSL_STRING` directly yield the same result.

Comment: @Dmitri The compilers are not required to do that, the behavior of clang is valid too.